# StateNotifierProvider en Riverpod flutter no notifica a la UI de cambios en el estado

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola estoy intentando configurar el estado de una app con Flutter y Riverpod y no he podido ya que parece por cierta circunstancia desconocida que el provider no está notificando de los cambios en el estado y por tanto la UI no se está reconstruyendo de acuerdo con estos cambios. La verdad soy un poco nuevo en esto por lo que pido me entiendan si es una 'bobada' muchas gracias:

```
//Este es el controller ->:

  class TestListController extends StateNotifier<List<TestQuestionModel>>{
  final TestRepository _testRepository;

  TestListController({
    required testRepository
  })
      : _testRepository = testRepository,
        super([]);

  late List<TestQuestionModel> _listQuestions;


    //carga la lista del archivo json usando el repositorio y la guarda en la
  // variable global
  void getQuestionList() async {

      final list = await _testRepository.loadJsonData();

      list.fold((l) => Failure(l.message),
                (r) => _listQuestions = r);
      state = _listQuestions;
    }



  void onCompleteTestQuestion(int index) {
    //trae la lista
    var list = state;
    //saca el elemento
    final question = list[index];
    //cambia el elemento
    final newQuestion = question.copyWith(answered: true);
    //cambia el nuevo elemento en la lista
    list[index] = newQuestion;
    //vuelve a poner la lista en la variable de estado
    state = list;

  }

  bool answeredTestQuestion(int index) {
    var list = state;
    return list[index].answered == true;

  }

bool isTheLastOneTest(int position) {
    final testList = state;
    if (position == testList.length - 1) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


}

//Este es el provider ->:

final testListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TestListController, List<TestQuestionModel>>((ref) {
  return TestListController(testRepository: ref.watch(testRepositoryProvider));



//Este es el widget que consume el provider ->:


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/features/onboarding/dominio/controllers/test_controller.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/test_question_model.dart';
import 'package:my_app/core/constants/dimensions.dart' as dimension;
import '../../../../core/common/dots_position.dart';
import '../../../../core/common/test_answers_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class TestScreenWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final int indexQuestion;
  final PageController pageController;
  final TestQuestionModel testQuestionModel;
  final VoidCallback onButtom;
  final List<TestQuestionModel> list;
  final Color _colorBack;


  TestScreenWidget(
      {
        required this.indexQuestion,
        required this.onButtom,
        required this.testQuestionModel,
        required this.pageController,
        required this.list,
  })  : _colorBack = OnboardingPresenters.getBackGroundColor(),
        super();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final position = ref.watch(testPositionProvider);
    final testListP = ref.watch(testListProvider);
    print('posición: $position');
    print('Esta es la lista: $testListP');
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: _colorBack,
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: screenSize.width / dimension.marginTextDefault,
                    right: screenSize.width / dimension.marginTextDefault),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                          height: screenSize.height / dimension.space50Ratio),
                      Text(
                        '${position + 1}.',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                          height: screenSize.height / dimension.space10Ratio),
                      Text(
                        testQuestionModel.content,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                          height: screenSize.height / dimension.space25Ratio),
                      Expanded(
                        child: SizedBox(
                          //padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 0, 0),
                          child: TestAnswersWidget(
                            indexQuestion: indexQuestion,
                              testQuestion: testQuestionModel),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                          children: [
                            DotsPostionWidget(
                              position: position,
                              list: list,
                            ),
                            //lógica para determinar si es la última pregunta
                            testListP[indexQuestion].answered == true ? Text('Si es  verdad') : Text('No es verdad')
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ])))); 



//Este es el widget desde donde se altera el estado del provider ->:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/test_question_model.dart';
import 'package:my_app/core/constants/dimensions.dart' as dimensions;
import '../../features/onboarding/dominio/controllers/test_controller.dart';

class TestAnswerTile extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final int indexQuestion;
  final testAnswersModel testAnswerModel;
  final TestQuestionModel testQuestionModel;
  TestAnswerTile(
      {required this.indexQuestion,
      super.key,
      required this.testAnswerModel,
      required this.testQuestionModel}) {
    /* print('El answer es: ${testAnswerModel.content}');
        print('El question es: ${testQuestionModel.content}'); */
  }

  @override
  ConsumerState<TestAnswerTile> createState() => _TestAnswerTileState();
}

class _TestAnswerTileState extends ConsumerState<TestAnswerTile> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listTestProvider = ref.read(testListProvider.notifier);
    final listAnswersProvider = ref.read(answersTestListControllerProvider.notifier);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: dimensions.marginTextDefault),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        width: 300,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              value: isChecked,
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              checkColor: Colors.black,
              focusColor: Colors.blue,
              side: const BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width: 2,
                  strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside),
              shape: const ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9))),
              onChanged: (bool? value) {

                  //se actualiza el valor de answered de la pregunta
                listTestProvider.onCompleteTestQuestion(widget.indexQuestion);

                final Map<TestQuestionModel, testAnswersModel> map = {
                  widget.testQuestionModel: widget.testAnswerModel
                };
                //se adiciona la repsuesta a la lista de respuestas del provider
                listAnswersProvider.onAnswerQuestion(map);

                setState(() {
                  isChecked = value!;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Text(
              widget.testAnswerModel.content,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Necesito que en el widget **TestScreenWidget** se cambie la UI cuando altero el estado del provider pero no sé porque no lo estoy logrando. Agradezo mucho a quien me pueda ayudar!!

Comment: No tengo ni idea de riverpod y hay demasiado código como para poder debugear rápido el problema, pero aquí te dejo unos consejos. Los modelos que estés actualizando tienen que implementar equals y hashcode de manera correcta para que riverpod pueda diferenciarlos, sino, nunca actualizarán. Además, si trabajas con listas, añadir o eliminar elementos, no disparará ningún cambio, tienes que crear una lista completamente nueva.